# Show name, not actual id

Tags: sql, oracle

```
SELECT T_EMP_ID

FROM TEACHER T1
WHERE NOT EXISTS
      (SELECT C1.CERT_ID

      FROM CERTIFICATION C1

      WHERE NOT EXISTS

          (SELECT TEI.CERT_ID

          FROM TEACHER_CERT_INT TEI

          WHERE C1.CERT_ID = TEI.CERT_ID

            AND T1.T_EMP_ID = TEI.T_EMP_ID

            AND sysdate >= TEI.DATE_EFFECTIVE

            AND sysdate <= TEI.DATE_EXPIRES));
```

I have this code and it should return a
list of all TEACHERs with current (in effect and not expired) certifications for every record (each record
represents some type of teacher certification/endorsement) that is listed in the CERTIFICATION table. When I run this in Oracle, it returns the one row that is supposed to show up, but instead of the EMPLOYEE name being shown, it shows the EMP_ID. How do I get this to work correctly, thanks.

Comment: Since nobody can likely guess the correct field name. Change "SELECT T_EMP_ID" to "SELECT * " then find the correct field name you are looking for. Then use "SELECT [Field_Name]"

Answer (score 0):

```
Select T1.firstname, t1.lastname
from .....
```

Just select the values you want to see or join to the table that has them

Answer (score 0):

When reading your question, I found your query rather confusing so I rewrote it in a way I can understand. If I understand correctly, you want to see the list of teachers who have active certifications in the `TEACHER_CERT_INT` table where they also exist in the `CERTIFICATION` table. Assuming that the name of the employee is in the `TEACHER` table and is named `EMPLOYEE`, the following code should do it.

```
SELECT DISTINCT T1.EMPLOYEE
FROM TEACHER T1 INNER JOIN
     TEACHER_CERT_INT TEI ON T1.T_EMP_ID = TEI.T_EMP_ID INNER JOIN
     CERTIFICATION C1 ON C1.CERT_ID = TEI.CERT_ID
WHERE sysdate >= TEI.DATE_EFFECTIVE AND sysdate <= TEI.DATE_EXPIRES
```

I used `DISTINCT` because any teacher with multiple certifications does not need to appear multiple times.